# Como repetir um código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá sou novo em python e gostaria de saber com repeito o código logo após seu término. Sendo que existem vários If e else no código.

Por via de dúvidas aqui está meu código.

```
print ("\n\t       CALCULADORA v 1.0\n")

escolha = str (input ("escolha a operação:\n (soma, subtraçao, divisao, multiplicaçao)\n\n"))

if escolha == "soma":
print ("==========================================")
print ("\t\t   SOMA")
print ("==========================================\n\n")

num1 = int (input ("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
num2 = int (input ("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))
resul= num1 + num2

print ("resultado:", resul)

else:
if escolha == "subtraçao":
    print ("==========================================")
    print ("\t\t SUBTRAÇÃO")
    print ("==========================================\n\n")

    num1 = int (input ("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
    num2 = int (input ("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))
    resul= num1 - num2

    print ("resultado:", resul)

else:

    if escolha == "divisao":
        print ("==========================================")
        print ("\t\t  DIVISÃO")
        print ("==========================================\n\n")

        num1 = int (input ("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
        num2 = int (input ("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))
        resul= num1 / num2

        print ("resultado:", resul)

    else:

        if escolha == "multiplicacao":
            print ("==========================================")
            print ("\t\tMULTIPLICAÇÃO")
            print ("==========================================\n\n")

            num1 = int (input ("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
            num2 = int (input ("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))
            resul= num1 * num2

            print ("resultado:", resul)
```

Comment: Desculpe o código ficou todo bagunçado não sei arrumar

Answer (score 2):

Tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas alterações, pois há muita repetição desnecessária.

- Primeiro, criei uma lista nomeada `operacoes`, nela contém as operações permitidas para poder validar a entrada do usuário.

  ```
  operacoes = {'soma', 'subtração', 'divisão', 'multiplicação'}
  ```
- Criei a variável `_repete` com o valor **42**, para que invés de poluir o código com vários caracteres `========...` basta apenas multiplica-ló pelo valor da variável: `"=" * _repete`
- Para repetir utilize `while`
- Para não haver repetição de código para cada título, pegamos a escolha do usuário e transformamos em *Uppercase*

  ```
  escolha.upper()
  ```
- Os `ifs` ficaram apenas para verificar qual operação foi escolhida e realiza-lá.

  ```
  if escolha == 'soma':
      resul= num1 + num2
  elif escolha == 'subtração':
      resul= num1 - num2
  elif escolha =='divisão':
      resul= num1 / num2
  else:
      resul= num1 * num2
  ```
- Caso a escolha feita pelo usuário não seja nenhuma das operações que está na lista ou a opção **sair**, irá retornar a mensagem **OPÇÃO INVÁLIDA!**.

  ```
  print("\nOPÇÃO INVÁLIDA!\n")
  ```

O código completo:

```
operacoes = {'soma', 'subtração', 'divisão', 'multiplicação'}
_repete = 42
print ("\n\t       CALCULADORA v 1.0\n")

while True:
    escolha = str (input ("escolha a operação:\n(soma, subtração, divisão, multiplicação)\n\n"))
    if escolha == 'sair':
        break
    elif escolha in operacoes:
        print("=" * _repete)
        print("\t\t", escolha.upper())
        print("=" * _repete, "\n\n")

        num1 = int (input ("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
        num2 = int (input ("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))

        if escolha == 'soma':
            resul= num1 + num2
        elif escolha == 'subtração':
            resul= num1 - num2
        elif escolha =='divisão':
            resul= num1 / num2
        else:
            resul= num1 * num2

        print ("resultado:", resul, "\n")
    else:
        print("\nOPÇÃO INVÁLIDA!\n")
```

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/KnowingTransparentChanticleer)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um while para executar a repetição com um parametro para parar a repetição, estou postando seu código sendo executado dentro de um While que repete o código até quando o usuario escolher a opção de saída digitando 'q', estou postando o seu próprio código sem refatorar, mas você deveria aninhar menos os IF's utilizando ELIF's ao invés de aninhar ELSE's e IF's.

Aqui esta seu código dentro do While:

```
print("\n\t CALCULADORA v 1.0\n")
print("Digite 'q' a qualquer momento para sair do programa")
while True:
    escolha = str(input("escolha a operação:\n (soma, subtraçao, divisao, multiplicaçao)\n\n"))
    if escolha == 'q':
        break
    elif escolha == "soma":
        print("==========================================")
        print("\t\t SOMA")
        print("==========================================\n\n")

        num1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
        num2 = int(input("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))
        resul= num1 + num2

        print("resultado: ", resul)

    else:

        if escolha == "subtraçao":
            print("==========================================")
            print("\t\t SUBTRAÇÃO")
            print("==========================================\n\n")

            num1 = int (input ("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
            num2 = int (input ("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))
            resul= num1 - num2

            print ("resultado:", resul)

        else:

            if escolha == "divisao":
                print ("==========================================")
                print ("\t\t  DIVISÃO")
                print ("==========================================\n\n")

                num1 = int (input ("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
                num2 = int (input ("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))
                resul= num1 / num2

                print ("resultado:", resul)

            else:

                if escolha == "multiplicacao":
                    print ("==========================================")
                    print ("\t\tMULTIPLICAÇÃO")
                    print ("==========================================\n\n")

                    num1 = int (input ("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
                    num2 = int (input ("\nDigite o segundo número.\n"))
                    resul= num1 * num2

                    print ("resultado:", resul)
```

E refatorando o código ficaria assim:

```
print("\n\t CALCULADORA v 1.0\n")
while True:
    print("Digite 'q' a qualquer momento para sair do programa")
    escolha = str(input("escolha a operação:\n (soma, subtraçao, divisao, multiplicaçao)\n\n"))
    if escolha == 'q':
        break
    num1 = input("Digite o primeiro número.\n")
    if num1 == 'q':
        break
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = input("\nDigite o segundo número.\n")
    if num2 == 'q':
        break
    num2 = int(num2)
    if escolha == "soma":
        print("==========================================")
        print("\t\t SOMA")
        print("==========================================\n\n")
        resul= num1 + num2
        print("resultado: ", resul)

    elif escolha == "subtraçao":
        print("==========================================")
        print("\t\t SUBTRAÇÃO")
        print("==========================================\n\n")

        resul= num1 - num2

        print ("resultado:", resul)

    elif escolha == "divisao":
        print ("==========================================")
        print ("\t\t  DIVISÃO")
        print ("==========================================\n\n")
        resul= num1 / num2

        print ("resultado:", resul)

    else:
        print ("==========================================")
        print ("\t\tMULTIPLICAÇÃO")
        print ("==========================================\n\n")

        resul= num1 * num2

        print ("resultado:", resul)
```

Bem melhor utilizando "elif" né!?

Comment: Oi Rapahel: achoq ue sua dica seria ainda mais útil se ensinasse o autor da pergunta a usar funções!

Answer (score -2):

```
print("\n\tCALCULADORA v1.0\n")

operations = {
    "soma": lambda x, y: x + y,
    "subtraçao": lambda x, y: x - y,
    "divisao": lambda x, y: x / y,
    "multiplicaçao": lambda x, y: x * y
}

escolha = input("Escolha a operação:\n(soma, subtraçao, divisao, multiplicaçao)\n\n").lower()

if escolha in operations:
    num1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro número.\n"))
    num2 = int(input("Digite o segundo número.\n"))
    result = operations[escolha](num1, num2)
    print("Resultado:", result)
else:
    print("Operação inválida!")
```